# Capitalize first letter in dropdown

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I seen a lot of post with regard to first letter capitalization using MySQL and stored procedure. I tried them all but none are working for me. Below is my code which I tried..

**PlansController.php**

```
$companies = $this->Plan->Company->find('list', array('conditions' =>   array('Company.status' => 'active'), 'fields' => array('Company.id','CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(Company.name, 1)),SUBSTRING(Company.name, 2)) as name'))); //Getting Empty Dropdown

$companies = $this->Plan->Company->find('list', array('conditions' => array('Company.status' => 'active'), 'fields' => array('Company.id', 'UCASE(Company.name)')));  //Getting Empty Dropdown

$companies = $this->Plan->Company->find('list', array('conditions' => array('Company.status' => 'active'), 'fields' => array('Company.id', 'Company.name')));  //Getting Dropdown in view
```

**View**

```
<select name="data[Plan][company_id]" class="" id="PlanCompanyId">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="2">xyz abc</option>
<option value="1">lmd abc</option>
<option value="13">Abc ey</option>
<option value="12">sys abc</option>
</select>
```

**Expecting output:**

```
<select name="data[Plan][company_id]" class="" id="PlanCompanyId">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="2">Xyz Abc</option>
    <option value="1">Lmd Abc</option>
    <option value="13">Abc Ey</option>
    <option value="12">Sys Abc</option>
    </select>
```

How can I capitalize the first letter of the dropdown?

Comment: Use virtual fields! http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution 1:  Use CSS:**

```
text-transform: capitalize;
```

**Solution 2: Virtual Field:**

[CakePHP's virtual fields](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html) (per mark's comment).  Basically, you create a virtual field that has any type of MySQL formatting/concatenating...etc and call it 'full_name' or something.  Then use IT for your drop-down instead of the  normal 'name'.